# PHP in .html file and .htaccess

Tags: php

I am trying to run a simple php code inside my html file. The file name is test.html.
The following code is inside the file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>My first PHP page</h1>

<?php
 echo "Hello World!";
 ?>

</body>
</html>
```

I have also changed my .htaccess file to include a code which my service provider recommended which is: AddHandler x-httpd-php .html.
But I still cannot display a simple message. Everything works fine if I change the file name to .php. But I want to keep my file name .html.
I can provide more info if required.

Comment: It's `AddHandler`, not `AddHandled`, there's a typo.

Comment: Yes, that's a typographical error. `AddHandler` is the correct syntax.

Comment: Where is your .htaccess file ????

Comment: It's located in the public folder. I am also placing my test.html file there.

Comment: `.htaccess` is sometimes tricky for seemingly no reason, since some things depend upon the server configuration. On that note, you could try asking on `http://serverfault.com/`. You could try `AddHandler fcgid-script .html` if using fast cgi. Or depending on your control panel use your control panel 'Add Extensions' tool (if available).

Comment: Something that will work (but isn't necessarily the "right" way) is if you add to your `.htaccess` `RewriteRule ^([^.]+)\.html$ /router.php`, then `router.php` in your root directory (public_html) will be loaded where you can do `include('/home/username/public_html'.$_SERVER('REQUEST_URI'));` BUT, you should use `realpath` and then make sure the path still starts in `/home/username/public_html` in case of `/../` in the request uri.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html .htm
```

or

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php5 .html .htm
```

or

```
RemoveHandler .html .htm
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html .htm
```

or

```
RemoveHandler .html .htm
AddType application/x-httpd-php5 .html .htm
```

Instead of

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .html .htm
```

Comment: I have tried all variant mentioned above except one that includes RemoveHandler. I will try that and see if it works.

Comment: If it still doesn't pick up your htaccess rules then apache is not set to allow override from htaccess. You need to set your virtual host to allow that before htaccess can take effect

Comment: Still not working. Man I don't know why this simple thing is so difficult.